# RMS amplitude of a sine wave

Tags: trigonometry

In some tutorials about digital signal processing the RMS (root means square) amplitude value of a sine wave is described to be 0.707 times the peak amplitude of a signal. How is this specific rms value achieved?

Answer (score 2):

If the signal is described as $f(t) = A \sin \omega t$, then the period is just $ T = 2\pi/\omega$ and

$$
{\rm RMS}(f) = \left[\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T{\rm d}t\;f^2(t)\right]^{1/2} = \left[\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}{\rm d}t\;(A\sin\omega t)^2\right]^{1/2} = \left[A^2 \frac{\pi}{2\pi}\right]^{1/2} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.7071 A
$$

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that $\sin^2 t = {1 \over 2} (1-\cos(2t))$.

Then $\sqrt{{1 \over 2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^2 t dt}  = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$.